# Load DOM elements while loading screen is displayed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-operator

I have created a loading screen component in my react app but have come acrosss an error regarding loading DOM elements in the background. Due to the way my ternary operator works either the `loadingScreen` component is displayed or the rest of the app is. This therefore only creates a delay and then loads my app. Rather than the desired effect of the `loadingScreen` component being displayed over the rest of my app while it loads and when effect reaches timeout the component disappears and the rest of app is shown.

I have investigated several methods using `componentDidMount` but my knowledge is lacking outside of functional React and have yet to find a method that doesnt re-create my current issue using React Hooks.

Heres how the rendering currently works:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import LoadingScreen from './components/loading';

import Header from './components/header';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Index from './components/index/index-page';
import Projects from './components/projects/projects-page';

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 3500) //Sets time spent loading
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {loading === false ? ( //If not in loading state
        <>
          <Header />
          
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Index />}/>
            <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />}/>
          </Routes>

          <Footer />
        </>
      ) : ( //Else calls loading screen
        <LoadingScreen />
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? It seems like you just want to display the loader with position fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a few months back on an app that I was working on. I got around it by making my Loading component show as position absolute, width of the screen, height of the screen and a high z-index to overlay other components.

Then I changed my turnary operator so that, instead of either showing Loading or the page's elements, it shows the pages elements and there is a turnary operator to show either the Loading component or null.